# Refreshing QListView not working

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview, qtsql, qsqltablemodel

Need some help finding why my `QListView` will not refresh.

I'm using `QListView` with a `QSqlTableModel`. I implement the model in the following function. I call this function from the class' constructor.

```cpp
void myclass::refresh()
{
     model_path = new QSqlTableModel(this);
     model_path->setTable("mytable");
     model_path->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
     model_path->select();
     ui->listView_path->setModel(model_path);
     ui->listView_path->setModelColumn(1);
 }
```

The following function will add a row and the `qlistView` refreshes without any issue.

```cpp
 void myclass::on_pushButton_add_clicked()
 {
     QSqlRecord rec (model_path->record());
     rec.setValue(1,ui->lineEdit->text());
     rec.setValue(2,2);

     model_path->insertRecord(-1, rec);
     emit model_path->layoutChanged();
 }
```

The following function will remove a row based on which line is highlighted in the `QListView`. The remove works as the row is deleted from the database once the `.submitAll` is done. However the `QListView` does not update consistently.

```cpp
 void myclass::on_pushButton_remove_clicked()
 {
     model_path->removeRow(ui->listView_path->currentIndex().row());
     emit model_path->dataChanged(ui->listView_path->currentIndex(),ui->listView_path->currentIndex());
     emit model_path->layoutChanged();
 }
```

If I delete a row, the list won't refresh. If I add one or more new rows, and then delete one or all of them, they will get refreshed. As you can see, I use both `dataChanged` and `layoutChanged` but they don't seem to do much here.

I don't understand why the refresh is not consistent. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call both `layoutChanged` or `dataChanged` when you add or delete some rows. They are not designed for such kind of updates. Check [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html)

Possible, your problem is in understanding edit strategy `QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit`. Try to change it to `QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using both `layoutChanged` and `dataChanged` only to show that neither works. Also OnManualSubmit is the right edit strategy for this as I only commit to changes at the end.